# How to create a few Machine Learning models through all variables and after each iteration next XGBClassifier is created with 1 less var in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning, roc, auc

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

**Input data:**

- Y - binnary target
- X1...X5 - predictors

  | Y | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 | X5 |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1 | 111 | 22 | 1 | 0 | 150 |
  | 0 | 12 | 33 | 1 | 0 | 222 |
  | 1 | 150 | 44 | 0 | 0 | 230 |
  | 0 | 270 | 55 | 0 | 1 | 500 |
  | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Requirements:**
And I need to:

- run a loop through all the variables in such a way that after each iteration a new XGBoost classification model is created and also after each iteration one of the variables is discarded and create next model
- So, if I have for example 5 predictors (X1...X5) I need to create 5 XGBoost classification models, and in in each successive model there must be 1 less variable
- Each model should be evaluated by `roc_auc_score`
- As an output I need: `list_of_models = []` where will be saved created models and DataFrame with  AUC on train and test

**Desire output:**

So, as a result I need to have something like below

- Model - position of model in list_of_models
- Num_var - number of predictors used in model
- AUC_train - roc_auc_score on train dataset
- AUC_test - roc_auc_score on test dataset

  | Model | Num_var | AUC_train | AUC_test |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 0 | 5 | 0.887 | 0.884 |
  | 1 | 4 | 0.875 | 0.845 |
  | 2 | 3 | 0.854 | 0.843 |
  | 3 | 2 | 0.965 | 0.928 |
  | 4 | 1 | 0.922 | 0.921 |

**My draft:** which is wrong because it should be loop through all the variables in such a way that after each iteration a new XGBoost classification model is created and also after each iteration one of the variables is discarded and create next model

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop("Y", axis=1)
                                                    , df.Y
                                                    , train_size = 0.70
                                                    , test_size=0.30
                                                    , random_state=1
                                                    , stratify = df.Y)

results = []
list_of_models = []

for val in X_train:

    model = XGBClassifier()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    list_of_models.append(model)

    preds_train = model.predict(X_train)
    preds_test = model.predict(X_test)
    preds_prob_train = model.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]
    preds_prob_test = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]

    results.append({("AUC_train":round(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_train,preds_prod_test),3),
                     "AUC_test":round(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test,preds_prod_test),3})

results = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

How can I do that in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make your data narrower during each loop? If I understand this correctly you could do something like this:

```
results = []
list_of_models = []

for i in X_train.columns:
    model = XGBClassifier()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    list_of_models.append(model)

    preds_train = model.predict(X_train)
    preds_test = model.predict(X_test)
    preds_prob_train = model.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]
    preds_prob_test = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
    results.append({("AUC_train":round(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_train,preds_prod_test),3),
                 "AUC_test":round(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test,preds_prod_test),3})
    X_train = X_train.drop(i, axis=1)
    X_test = X_test.drop(i, axis=1)

results = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: Yes, each subsequent model is to be built with 1 less variable than the previous one. does your solution made it ?

Comment: MichaelB, but how to make in output DF also column Num_var? because using your solution i have only variables in output DF: Model, AUC_train, AUC_test ?

Comment: Use your existing code but change the loop params and append the drop functions to the end of the loop.

Comment: MichaelB, could you also add in DataFrame column with name of feature which is dropped during each iteration ? because now we do not know which varaible was dropped ?

Comment: Append a different list with i.